# python selenium . how to switch back to previous window/tab after a download opens up a new tab

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

The problem is when I download a file through a click(), it opens a new tab/window to initiate the download, then the browser automatically closes the tab/window. However, when I want to access the previous page in which the download link was, I get the error "invalid session id".

I get the error "**No such window exception**" when using Safari for the automation.

If anyone knows how to deal with this issue I would appreciate all the help I could get. thank you all!

my code is below and the error comes after trying to click `file_dl2`

```
attachments = browser.find_element_by_id('sAttachments')
attachments.click() 

time.sleep(2)

files = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FileListFI"]/div[1]') 
files.click()

file_dl = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_chpDialog_hrefFileLink"]/img')  
file_dl.click()

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

file_dl2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl01_chpDialog_hrefFileLink"]/img') 
file_dl2.click()
```

Comment: We need to see your current code and where it's not working, any error messages in full, etc.

Comment: From your description: 1) you are on a page in browser #1 and click a link, 2) the site opens a new window in browser #2 which downloads the file then closes browser #2 leaving browser #1. If this is the case, you don't have to switch windows at all. Selenium doesn't switch automatically to the new window, etc. You have to tell it when you want to switch. If this is not the case, list out your steps clearly so we can better understand what you are trying to do and where it stops working.

Comment: @JeffC i have posted the code above as an edit. I didint switch any windows with selenium but it still wont work.

Comment: Please format your code as code and you still need to clearly explain the flow of steps (with words) so we can understand the scenario.

Comment: if possible share url.. to try

Comment: You haven't posted any code that switches windows. You also haven't posted step by step instructions of what you want you script to do and when the windows open/close. We can't help you if you don't provide all this info.

Answer (score -1):

```
....
     driver.get("<web-site>")
                sleep(1)
....
```

> This fetches the original/previous website is fetched (add this code where you have click() action in role ).

> You can append new set of instruction after sleep() function and wrok further.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with switching windows and if he's in the second window and does driver.get, he'll end up driving the second window leaving the first window orphaned.

Comment: can you elaborate more ?

Comment: The question is how to switch windows. This does not address the question. If he has two windows open and is switched to the second window, using driver.get will just start driving the second window leaving the first.

Comment: yeah, i kept thinking tht flaw ,  iguess i will delete my answer , sorry for inconvinence